# Asserted precondition might not hold in mutual inductive Dafny lemmas

Tags: dafny

I am trying to prove something about the semantics of programs with side-effects in Dafny using trees that record the interaction, following the free monad approach. Thus, what the semantics will produce are trees of the following shape (simplified to only one instruction for reading an input).

```dafny
datatype Prog<A>
  = Return (pure : A)
  | Get(input : string -> Prog<A>)
```

The main issue is that these are infinitely branching trees and it requires some trickery to work with such trees in Dafny because they have no bound on the depth, although every leaf is reachable via a finite path.

What I would like to do now is to define big-step semantics as inductive relation, [see the article "Well-founded Functions and Extreme Predicates in Dafny: A Tutorial"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/krml250.pdf). Here is a small part of the language, just with one command for reading and one for sequential composition of commands. The relation `big_step_bind` sequentially composes two interaction trees (bind is the usual terminology for the map that composes monadic computations), while `big_step` is the big-step semantics relation. These relations are inductively and mutually defined.

```dafny
datatype Com =  GetC | SeqC(Com, Com)

type Store = map<int, string>

least predicate big_step_bind(c : Com, p : Prog<Store>, q : Prog<Store>) {
  match p {
    case Return(s) => big_step(c, s, q)
    case Get(f)    => exists g :: q == Get(g) && forall i :: big_step_bind(c, f(i), g(i))
  }
}

least predicate big_step(c : Com, s : Store, p : Prog<Store>) {
  match c {
    case GetC =>
      p == Get(i => Return(s[0 := i]))
    case SeqC(c1, c2) =>
      exists p1 :: big_step(c1, s, p1) && big_step_bind(c2, p1, p)
  }
}
```

So far, everything works reasonably well. But to run any functions on the resulting interaction trees, I need to know that the big-step semantics only gives well-founded trees because Dafny will not allow definitions by recursion over `Prog` and complain about non-termination. Thus, I define a predicate `wfTree` that singles out all well-founded trees of the type `Prog`, which should in fact be all of them.

```dafny
least predicate wfTree<A> (p : Prog<A>){
  match p {
    case Return(b) => true
    case Get(g)    => forall x :: wfTree(g(x))
  }
}
```

### Problem

Now I would like to prove that all trees "produced" by the big-step semantics are well-founded:

```dafny
least lemma big_step_bind_wf(c : Com, p : Prog<Store>, q : Prog<Store>)
  requires wfTree(p)                                      // (1)
  requires big_step_bind(c, p, q)
  ensures wfTree(q)
{
  match p {
    case Return(s) => big_step_wf(c, s, q);
    case Get(f) =>
      var i ;
      var q' :| big_step_bind(c, f(i), q');
      big_step_bind_wf(c, f(i), q');
  }
}

least lemma big_step_wf(c : Com, s : Store, p : Prog<Store>)
  requires big_step(c, s, p)
  ensures wfTree(p)
{
  match c {
    case GetC => return;
    case SeqC(c1, c2) =>
      var p1 :| big_step(c1, s, p1) && big_step_bind(c2, p1, p);
      big_step_wf(c1, s, p1);                             // (2)
      assert wfTree(p1);                                  // (3)
      big_step_bind_wf(c2, p1, p);                        // (4)
  }
}
```

Again, these lemmas are mutually proven by induction. However, the last step (4) of the proof cannot be verified. Dafny says

> Error: A precondition for this call might not hold.

and refers to (1), which is the precondition of `big_step_bind_wf` that requires `wfTree(p1)` to hold. However, (2) has as postcondition exactly that and the `assert` at (3) shows this.

My question is now: Why can Dafny not be sure that the precondition holds? Am I missing something or is this an issue with the implementation? Thank you very much!

Comment: I am trying to understand big step semantics definition. Added a lemma with assert 
`assert  big_step_bind(SeqC(GetC, GetC), Get(x => Return (map[0 := x])), Get(y => Return (map[0 := y])) );` which failed. Is it not intended semantics or something is wrong with this assert.

Comment: This is not quite correct. The expected result of your call to `big_step_bind` is `Get(i => Get(upd(s[0 := i])))`, where `upd(s) = i => Return(s[0 := i]))`. Here is a proof:

```
function upd(s : Store): string -> Prog<Store>{
  i => Return(s[0 := i])
}
lemma Get2(s : Store)
  ensures big_step(SeqC(GetC, GetC), s, Get(i => Get(upd(s[0 := i]))))
{
  // Get1(s);
  // GetGet(s);
  assert big_step(GetC, s, Get(upd(s)));
  assert forall i :: big_step_bind(GetC, upd(s)(i), Get(upd(s[0 := i])));
  assert big_step_bind(GetC, Get(upd(s)), Get(i => Get(upd(s[0 := i]))));
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Problem seems to be different ordinal parameters of least predicates. As far as I know for least predicate P, it means some ordinal k exists such that P#[k] is true, I am not sure how it translates to least predicate as precondition. 

Adding `assume forall m :: wfTree#[m](p1)` before (4) makes verification succeed.  My guess is some tracking of proof tree height is required for dafny to verify it.

Comment: I think that you are right about this. Unfortunately, I did not succeed in setting up invariants properly to track the involved ordinals. One of the steps involved is to show that if g(i) is a wf tree of with ordinal k - 1, then Get(g) is wf with k. But already showing that gives me a timeout: `lemma GetStepWf (k : ORDINAL, k' : ORDINAL, g : string -> Prog<Store>)
  requires k' < k
  requires forall i :: wfTree#[k'](g(i))
  ensures wfTree#[k](Get(g))
{}`. If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Ok, I found that I can suppress induction with `{:induction false}` but then the lemma cannot be proven as it is. Unfortunately, I don't know how Dafny handles ordinals in the definition of wfTree.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to verify by moving well founded program precondition to postcondition in least lemma for bind.

```java
datatype Program<T> = Result(T) | Get(input: string -> Program<T>)
    
datatype Command = GetInput | Sequence(Command, Command)
    
    
least predicate big_step_bind
   (c: Command,
    p1: Program<string>,
    p2: Program<string>)
{
    match p1 {
      case Result(x) => big_step(c, p2)
      case Get(pr) =>
         exists qr :: p2 == Get(qr)
            && forall i :: big_step_bind(c, pr(i), qr(i))
    }
}
    
least predicate big_step(c: Command, p: Program<string>){
    match c  {
      case GetInput => p == Get(input => Result(input))
      case Sequence(c1, c2) =>
       exists p1 ::  big_step(c1, p1) && big_step_bind(c2, p1, p)
    }
}
    
least predicate wellFoundedProgram(p: Program<string>)
{
   match p {
     case Result(x) => true
     case Get(px) => forall i ::  wellFoundedProgram(px(i))
   }
}
    
    
least lemma wellFoundedGenerationBind(c: Command, p1: Program<string>, p: Program<string>)
   requires big_step_bind(c, p1, p)
   ensures wellFoundedProgram(p1)
   ensures wellFoundedProgram(p)
{
   match p1 {
     case Result(x) => { wellFoundedGeneration(c, p) ;}
     case Get(px) => {
     }
   }
}
    
least lemma wellFoundedGeneration(c: Command, p: Program<string>)
  requires big_step(c, p)
  ensures wellFoundedProgram(p)
{
   match c {
     case GetInput => {}
     case Sequence(c1, c2) => {
        var p1 :| big_step(c1, p1) && big_step_bind(c2, p1, p);
        wellFoundedGenerationBind(c2, p1, p);
     }
   }
}
```